# How can I get selenium/geckodriver to work?

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping, geckodriver

This is my first python project and I can't get the selenium/geckodriver to work properly. I'm using debian 10.

I put geckodriver in the PATH and made it executable, installed the right firefox and everything is up to date.

This is the supposed code and it should at least get me to google.com, instead it gives me an error:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    import time



class Snelstart:
    def __init__(self,username,password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.bot = webdriver.Firefox()
    def login(self):
        bot = self.bot
        bot.get("https://www.google.com")
        time.sleep(3)

ed = Snelstart('loginner', 'pass123')
ed.login
```

This code gives the error: `selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities`

Next I got multiple other attempts, but they all encounter one problem or another:

This code:

```
`from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time

cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = False

class Snelstart:
    def __init__(self,username,password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.bot = webdriver.Firefox()
    def login(self):
        bot = self.bot
        bot.get("https://web.snelstart.nl/login")
        time.sleep(3)

ed = Snelstart('loginner', 'pass123')
ed.login`
```

gives me a blank firefox page, followed by this error: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: The browser appears to have exited before we could connect.`

I've also tried giving `webdriver.Firefox()` an `executable_path/to/geckodriver`. This still gives the first error. And `executable_path/to/firefox` gives me again a blank page. Also adding the `firefox_binary` method gives no result.

I can't find anything else on this problem. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Following browser versions and trying to keep up drivers (Geckodriver in your case) synced up can be tiring.

There are some solutions that do that automatically for you. In Java I use WebDriverManager. I haven't used something similar for Python but I found [Webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/).

Simply use it like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
```

Webdriver manager should check the latest version of the driver and install it for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It installed gecko again now the right way, but still have the same error.

'selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities'

Comment: I guess webdriver manager defaults to the latest version. Maybe your Firefox version is not up to date?

Comment: Try adding "version='XX'" to GeckoDriverManager() constructor, where XX is the version matching your Firefox version.

Comment: 'driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager(version='81.0.2').install())'

this gives error: 'ValueError: There is no such driver by url'

so still no succes.

Comment: I tried this and I'm getting TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'. Were you able to get this to work?